# Setting object properties with or without the C# 'new' keyword

Tags: c#

Is there a fundamental difference in setting object properties with or without the `new` keyword?

The following is an example to illustrate what I am referring to, shown under Case 1 and Case 2. Wherever possible intend to use Case 2 (looks neat as a single statement) but couldn't be sure if the C# `new` keyword has any downsides such as increased memory usage. @Dennis_E I've already voted +1 ;-)

**Amended Supplement:**
Thank you all with prompt comments and answer. You know comments and answers jog related points which you never thought of when the question was posed. Forgive me for amending but hope you understand.

Suppose the code in Case 1 and Case 2 are used numerous times (say as you navigate into a view page) does Case 2 have a disadvantage in increasing memory. Perhaps I am making a wrong assumption here -- does 'new'ing up the same variable create a new object?? May be this is the fundamental question.

```
    public static class MyCache
    {
        public static NameIdObject MyCacheObject = new NameIdObject();
    }

    public class NameIdObject
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }

    // Usage 1: without new keyword

    MyCache.MyCacheObject.Name = "foo";
    MyCache.MyCacheObject.Id = 123;

    // Usage 2: with new keyword

    MyCache.MyCacheObject = new NameIdObject { Id = 123, Name = "foo" };
```

Comment: both the cases are similar in terms of how the object is being constructed.`MyCache.MyCacheObject` is always initialized.

Comment: In regards to memory, they are pretty much equal. Case 2 uses lazy instantiation, which does delay the allocation of memory. This is more a decision of design though. EDIT: This assumes that, in Case 2, you don't initialize the object directly in `MyCache`.

Answer (score 3):

The `new` keyword has nothing to do with setting properties. It creates a new object. However, an object initializer can only be used in combination with creating a new object.

The statement

```
MyCache.MyCacheObject = new NameIdObject { Id = 123, Name = "foo" };
```

is an object initializer. It is just a more convenient way of writing (and is equivalent to):

```
MyCache.MyCacheObject = new NameIdObject();
MyCache.MyCacheObject.Id = 123;
MyCache.MyCacheObject.Name = "foo";
```

Your first code sample only sets the property values. It does not instantiate a new object. (You would have done that earlier, in a separate statement)
So the fundamental difference is: you are creating a new object.

Comment: Thank you @Dennis_E -- Having read the answer, may be my question needs some amending. Suppose the code in Case 1 and Case 2 are used numerous times (say as you navigate into a view page) does Case 2 have a disadvantage in increasing memory. Perhaps I am making a wrong assumption here -- does 'new'ng up the same variable create another object?? May be this is the fundamental question.

Comment: Sort of. Every time you call 'new' youre creating a new instance of an object. This incurs a computational overhead (and a new pointer on the stack etc). As there are no longer any references to the old object, it will be cleaned up by the garbage collector (at some point), but for a short period of time, both objects will exist in memory.

Comment: I wasn't sure I understood. Every time you call `new`, you are creating a new object. Your variable will then reference this new object. The old object will still be in memory also (but no longer referenced by your variable). If you just change the property values, you are not creating a new object.

Comment: Perhaps that's where my confusion lies. I thought 'new'ing up an existing object just retrieves an existing object (my logic being *create new only if the object doesn't exist* -- is there any logic in deleting an existing and creating new anyway??). In that case I see the disadvantage of the new keyword if the code is used repeatedly, Am I right?

Comment: There's no such thing as "newing up an existing object". `new` always creates a new object (and returns a reference to it). A variable and the actual object are separate things. An object doesn't know about any variables, multiple variables can reference the same object and a variable can change which object it references.

Comment: I get it absolutely @Dennis_E. What was I thinking? MyCache.MyCacheObject just holds a reference and gets updated with a new reference every time equated to new object creation. It's one of those hazy situation which gets cleared when someone tells you clearly. Don't know what I was thinking-got this funny but wrong notion in my head that the reference stays the same if it's non-null. A wrong and dangerous assumption on my part. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Nice way to check this is to write little files, compile them and check with IL Spy what they do in the intermediate language. If i do that with this case i get to files. Here is the C# code.

```
using System;

namespace test
{
    public class NameIdObject
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }

    public static class MyCache
    {
        public static NameIdObject MyCacheObject = new NameIdObject();
    }

    public static class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            MyCache.MyCacheObject.Name = "foo";
            MyCache.MyCacheObject.Id = 123;

        }
    }
}
```

**Case 2**

```
using System;

namespace test
{
    public class NameIdObject
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }

    public static class MyCache
    {
        public static NameIdObject MyCacheObject;
    }

    public static class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            MyCache.MyCacheObject = new NameIdObject { Id = 123, Name = "foo" };
        }
    }
}
```

When you compile that trough the Developer Command Line. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78f4aasd.aspx for more information about that. You can view the intermediate language with IL Spy

Below are the results:

**Case 1**

```
.namespace test
{
    .class public auto ansi abstract sealed beforefieldinit test.MyCache
        extends [mscorlib]System.Object
    {
        // Fields
        .field public static class test.NameIdObject MyCacheObject

        // Methods
        .method private hidebysig specialname rtspecialname static 
            void .cctor () cil managed 
        {
            // Method begins at RVA 0x207b
            // Code size 11 (0xb)
            .maxstack 8

            IL_0000: newobj instance void test.NameIdObject::.ctor()
            IL_0005: stsfld class test.NameIdObject test.MyCache::MyCacheObject
            IL_000a: ret
        } // end of method MyCache::.cctor

    } // end of class test.MyCache

    .class public auto ansi beforefieldinit test.NameIdObject
        extends [mscorlib]System.Object
    {
        // Fields
        .field private string '<Name>k__BackingField'
        .custom instance void [mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute::.ctor() = (
            01 00 00 00
        )
        .custom instance void [mscorlib]System.Diagnostics.DebuggerBrowsableAttribute::.ctor(valuetype [mscorlib]System.Diagnostics.DebuggerBrowsableState) = (
            01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
        )
        .field private int32 '<Id>k__BackingField'
        .custom instance void [mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute::.ctor() = (
            01 00 00 00
        )
        .custom instance void [mscorlib]System.Diagnostics.DebuggerBrowsableAttribute::.ctor(valuetype [mscorlib]System.Diagnostics.DebuggerBrowsableState) = (
            01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
        )

        // Methods
        .method public hidebysig specialname 
            instance string get_Name () cil managed 
        {
            .custom instance void [mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute::.ctor() = (
                01 00 00 00
            )
            // Method begins at RVA 0x2050
            // Code size 7 (0x7)
            .maxstack 8

            IL_0000: ldarg.0
            IL_0001: ldfld string test.NameIdObject::'<Name>k__BackingField'
            IL_0006: ret
        } // end of method NameIdObject::get_Name

        .method public hidebysig specialname 
            instance void set_Name (
                string 'value'
            ) cil managed 
        {
            .custom instance void [mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute::.ctor() = (
                01 00 00 00
            )
            // Method begins at RVA 0x2058
            // Code size 8 (0x8)
            .maxstack 8

            IL_0000: ldarg.0
            IL_0001: ldarg.1
            IL_0002: stfld string test.NameIdObject::'<Name>k__BackingField'
            IL_0007: ret
        } // end of method NameIdObject::set_Name

        .method public hidebysig specialname 
            instance int32 get_Id () cil managed 
        {
            .custom instance void [mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute::.ctor() = (
                01 00 00 00
            )
            // Method begins at RVA 0x2061
            // Code size 7 (0x7)
            .maxstack 8

            IL_0000: ldarg.0
            IL_0001: ldfld int32 test.NameIdObject::'<Id>k__BackingField'
            IL_0006: ret
        } // end of method NameIdObject::get_Id

        .method public hidebysig specialname 
            instance void set_Id (
                int32 'value'
            ) cil managed 
        {
            .custom instance void [mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute::.ctor() = (
                01 00 00 00
            )
            // Method begins at RVA 0x2069
            // Code size 8 (0x8)
            .maxstack 8

            IL_0000: ldarg.0
            IL_0001: ldarg.1
            IL_0002: stfld int32 test.NameIdObject::'<Id>k__BackingField'
            IL_0007: ret
        } // end of method NameIdObject::set_Id

        .method public hidebysig specialname rtspecialname 
            instance void .ctor () cil managed 
        {
            // Method begins at RVA 0x2072
            // Code size 8 (0x8)
            .maxstack 8

            IL_0000: ldarg.0
            IL_0001: call instance void [mscorlib]System.Object::.ctor()
            IL_0006: nop
            IL_0007: ret
        } // end of method NameIdObject::.ctor

        // Properties
        .property instance string Name()
        {
            .get instance string test.NameIdObject::get_Name()
            .set instance void test.NameIdObject::set_Name(string)
        }
        .property instance int32 Id()
        {
            .get instance int32 test.NameIdObject::get_Id()
            .set instance void test.NameIdObject::set_Id(int32)
        }

    } // end of class test.NameIdObject

    .class public auto ansi abstract sealed beforefieldinit test.Programm
        extends [mscorlib]System.Object
    {
        // Methods
        .method public hidebysig static 
            void Main () cil managed 
        {
            // Method begins at RVA 0x2087
            // Code size 31 (0x1f)
            .maxstack 8
            .entrypoint

            IL_0000: nop
            IL_0001: ldsfld class test.NameIdObject test.MyCache::MyCacheObject
            IL_0006: ldstr "foo"
            IL_000b: callvirt instance void test.NameIdObject::set_Name(string)
            IL_0010: nop
            IL_0011: ldsfld class test.NameIdObject test.MyCache::MyCacheObject
            IL_0016: ldc.i4.s 123
            IL_0018: callvirt instance void test.NameIdObject::set_Id(int32)
            IL_001d: nop
            IL_001e: ret
        } // end of method Programm::Main

    } // end of class test.Programm

}
```

**Case 2**

```
.namespace test
{
    .class public auto ansi abstract sealed beforefieldinit test.MyCache
        extends [mscorlib]System.Object
    {
        // Fields
        .field public static class test.NameIdObject MyCacheObject

    } // end of class test.MyCache

    .class public auto ansi beforefieldinit test.NameIdObject
        extends [mscorlib]System.Object
    {
        // Fields
        .field private string '<Name>k__BackingField'
        .custom instance void [mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute::.ctor() = (
            01 00 00 00
        )
        .custom instance void [mscorlib]System.Diagnostics.DebuggerBrowsableAttribute::.ctor(valuetype [mscorlib]System.Diagnostics.DebuggerBrowsableState) = (
            01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
        )
        .field private int32 '<Id>k__BackingField'
        .custom instance void [mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute::.ctor() = (
            01 00 00 00
        )
        .custom instance void [mscorlib]System.Diagnostics.DebuggerBrowsableAttribute::.ctor(valuetype [mscorlib]System.Diagnostics.DebuggerBrowsableState) = (
            01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
        )

        // Methods
        .method public hidebysig specialname 
            instance string get_Name () cil managed 
        {
            .custom instance void [mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute::.ctor() = (
                01 00 00 00
            )
            // Method begins at RVA 0x2050
            // Code size 7 (0x7)
            .maxstack 8

            IL_0000: ldarg.0
            IL_0001: ldfld string test.NameIdObject::'<Name>k__BackingField'
            IL_0006: ret
        } // end of method NameIdObject::get_Name

        .method public hidebysig specialname 
            instance void set_Name (
                string 'value'
            ) cil managed 
        {
            .custom instance void [mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute::.ctor() = (
                01 00 00 00
            )
            // Method begins at RVA 0x2058
            // Code size 8 (0x8)
            .maxstack 8

            IL_0000: ldarg.0
            IL_0001: ldarg.1
            IL_0002: stfld string test.NameIdObject::'<Name>k__BackingField'
            IL_0007: ret
        } // end of method NameIdObject::set_Name

        .method public hidebysig specialname 
            instance int32 get_Id () cil managed 
        {
            .custom instance void [mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute::.ctor() = (
                01 00 00 00
            )
            // Method begins at RVA 0x2061
            // Code size 7 (0x7)
            .maxstack 8

            IL_0000: ldarg.0
            IL_0001: ldfld int32 test.NameIdObject::'<Id>k__BackingField'
            IL_0006: ret
        } // end of method NameIdObject::get_Id

        .method public hidebysig specialname 
            instance void set_Id (
                int32 'value'
            ) cil managed 
        {
            .custom instance void [mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute::.ctor() = (
                01 00 00 00
            )
            // Method begins at RVA 0x2069
            // Code size 8 (0x8)
            .maxstack 8

            IL_0000: ldarg.0
            IL_0001: ldarg.1
            IL_0002: stfld int32 test.NameIdObject::'<Id>k__BackingField'
            IL_0007: ret
        } // end of method NameIdObject::set_Id

        .method public hidebysig specialname rtspecialname 
            instance void .ctor () cil managed 
        {
            // Method begins at RVA 0x2072
            // Code size 8 (0x8)
            .maxstack 8

            IL_0000: ldarg.0
            IL_0001: call instance void [mscorlib]System.Object::.ctor()
            IL_0006: nop
            IL_0007: ret
        } // end of method NameIdObject::.ctor

        // Properties
        .property instance string Name()
        {
            .get instance string test.NameIdObject::get_Name()
            .set instance void test.NameIdObject::set_Name(string)
        }
        .property instance int32 Id()
        {
            .get instance int32 test.NameIdObject::get_Id()
            .set instance void test.NameIdObject::set_Id(int32)
        }

    } // end of class test.NameIdObject

    .class public auto ansi abstract sealed beforefieldinit test.Program
        extends [mscorlib]System.Object
    {
        // Methods
        .method public hidebysig static 
            void Main () cil managed 
        {
            // Method begins at RVA 0x207b
            // Code size 33 (0x21)
            .maxstack 8
            .entrypoint

            IL_0000: nop
            IL_0001: newobj instance void test.NameIdObject::.ctor()
            IL_0006: dup
            IL_0007: ldc.i4.s 123
            IL_0009: callvirt instance void test.NameIdObject::set_Id(int32)
            IL_000e: nop
            IL_000f: dup
            IL_0010: ldstr "foo"
            IL_0015: callvirt instance void test.NameIdObject::set_Name(string)
            IL_001a: nop
            IL_001b: stsfld class test.NameIdObject test.MyCache::MyCacheObject
            IL_0020: ret
        } // end of method Program::Main

    } // end of class test.Program

}
```

Now with this information you van analyse what the system is doing with your code. You can see in case 1 that the instance of NameIdObject is created in the constructor of MyCache object. While in case 2 the instance of the NameIdObject is created in the main function of program.

So the place where the object instance is created and with that the time that the instance is created is different. I hope this help to decide which case is the most efficient for your program.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to give more insight into the answer.